# How to add div after 3 rows in Joomla intro_items

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm working on adding this to the com_content blog.php override.

Where we have the intro_items I need to have it count through 3 articles and then add a div where I can drop an ad script and than have it carry on and load the remaining 7 articles.

This is the intro_items loop. In parameters I have it set to 10 articles

```
<?php
$introcount = count($this->intro_items);
$counter = 0;
?>

<?php if (!empty($this->intro_items)) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : ?>
        <?php $rowcount = ((int) $key % (int) $this->columns) + 1; ?>
        <?php if ($rowcount === 1) : ?>
            <?php $row = $counter / $this->columns; ?>
            <div class="items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns; ?> <?php echo 'row-' . $row; ?> row-fluid clearfix">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="span<?php echo round(12 / $this->columns); ?>">
            <div class="item column-<?php echo $rowcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>"
                itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <?php
                $this->item = &$item;
                echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                ?>
            </div>
            <!-- end item -->
            <?php $counter++; ?>
        </div><!-- end span -->
        <?php if (($rowcount == $this->columns) or ($counter == $introcount)) : ?>
            </div><!-- end row -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I came up with the following, which works, but would like an opinion if there is a better way to do this.

```
    <?php
$introcount = count($this->intro_items);
$counter = 0;
?>

<?php if (!empty($this->intro_items)) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : ?>
        <?php $rowcount = ((int) $key % (int) $this->columns) + 1; ?>
        <?php if ($rowcount === 1) : ?>
            <?php $row = $counter / $this->columns; ?>
            <div class="items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns; ?> <?php echo 'row-' . $row; ?> row-fluid clearfix">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($row != 2) : ?>       
            <div class="span<?php echo round(12 / $this->columns); ?>">
                <div class="item column-<?php echo $rowcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>"
                    itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                    <?php
                    $this->item = &$item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                    ?>
                </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($row === 2) : ?>
                <div class="span<?php echo round(12 / $this->columns); ?>">
                <div class="item column-<?php echo $rowcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>"
                    itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                    <?php
                    $this->item = &$item;
                    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
                    ?>
                    <!-- mobile ad banner zone -->
                    <div class="cat-banner bannerzonepadding visible-phone">
                        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://myadsrc.demo"></script>
                     </div>
                </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- end item -->
                <?php $counter++; ?>
            </div><!-- end span --> 
        <?php if (($rowcount == $this->columns) or ($counter == $introcount)) : ?>
            </div><!-- end row -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this approach work?

- you add an ID to a wrapper around your list of intro_items
- use jQuery and CSS nth-child selector to target the third child in the intro_items list
- then use jQuery .after() function to insert the HTML for your ad

Pseudo code

```
 $("#intro_items_wrapper .items-row:nth-child(3)").after('<!-- mobile ad code here -->');
```

Actual code

```
 $("#intro_items_wrapper .items-row:nth-child(3)").after('<!-- mobile ad banner zone -->
<div class="cat-banner bannerzonepadding visible-phone">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://myadsrc.demo"></script>
</div>');
```

Here's a working demo:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/EEwaQX

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will test it out and reply back. Hopefully in good time.